# Cannot remove firestore listener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I call remove(), but listener is still working.
I want to call result(true) just onece.

```swift
var listener: ListenerRegistration!

func setListener(result:@escaping(Bool)-> Void){
    listener = ref.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if ...
            result(true)
            self.removeListener
    } 
}

func removeListener() {
    if listener != nil {
        listener.remove()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to query only once, why are you using a listener?  Just use getDocuments(). https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#getdocumentscompletion:

Comment: I want to detect when the document was changed by another device.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting mutable listener to the same variable. That was the reason.